# Check if uri string matches any pattern in list

Tags: php, regex

I want to check if the current `$uri_string` matches any of these patterns

```
$uri_string = 'project/details/1258';

$uri_patterns = [
   'project/foo/',
    'project/bizz/',
];


foreach($uri_patterns as $pattern) {
    if(preg_match('/' . $pattern. '/i', $uri_string) == 1) {
        echo 'Is a match!';
    }
}
```

so if at some point the `$uri_string = 'project/foo/123/some-other-params';` then this sould match the `'project/foo/'` pattern. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to escape the `/` slashes from your regex like:

```
$uri_string = 'project/details/1258';

$uri_patterns = [
   'project/foo/',
    'project/bizz/',
];


foreach($uri_patterns as $pattern) {
    $pattern = preg_quote($pattern, '/');
    if(preg_match("/$pattern/i", $uri_string) == 1) {
        echo 'Is a match!';
    }
}
```

This uses [`preg_quote()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php) to escape the slashes.

Alternatively, you can use different `delimiter` for the regex, like `#`:

```
 preg_match("#$pattern#i", $uri_string);
```

Or you can ignore regex completely and use string parsing functions like:

```
foreach($uri_patterns as $pattern) {
    if(strpos($uri_string, $pattern) !== false) {
        echo 'Is a match!';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you'll need to escape those forward slashes:

```
$uri_patterns = [
    'project\/foo\/',
    'project\/bizz\/',
];
```

Then for your match, use:

```
preg_match('/' . $pattern . '/i', $uri_string, $matches);
if (!empty($matches)) {
    echo 'Is a match!';
}
```